# Editing into multiple HTML Pages

Tags: html

I have my HTML website that contains about 330+ HTML files. But, each time I want to edit some code or tags, I get Stuck at that moment.
I searched the net throughly, but couldn't find a single Free Tool that could do this. I used Notepad++, but that Replaces the text by a single Tag.

Comment: can you post some tag or snippet to change. i guess you can use the regular expression search and replace for that.

Comment: What does "Stuck at that momoment" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Something like http://www.wingrep.com/ can find and replace across multiple files, if you want to change code blocks en masse.

Comment: Thanks Dude. I think that's gonna help me.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something to look at for the future would be using php to import your header, footer and sidebar from separate files. That way you only need to change one file.

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>

<?php include 'footer.php';?>

<?php include 'sidebar.php';?>
```

Not much use to you now but maybe the most useful thing i've come across lately :0)

---

To prevent RFI attacks (I came across this in an article somewhere)

```
 Here we check our query string for http://, https:// or ftp://

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(http|https|ftp):\/\/(.*)

 If you are using this rewrite within a .htaccess all you have left is to deny access from all matching requests.

 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [F]

 If you have access to your vhost you could also log those requests like this:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(http|https|ftp):\/\/(.*)
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=rfi:true]
</IfModule>

CustomLog /path/to/logs/rfi.log combined env=rfi

You will also have to deny access from requests that have been caught by the above rewrite

Deny from env=rfi
```

Comment: But, doing this would make my website vulnerable to RFI Attack.. And might get hacked easily... :)

Comment: Dammit! I hadn't come across that yet. You can prevent RFI attacks using Mod Rewrite.

Comment: You're not going to get an RFI attack with a hard-coded string like `'header.php'`.  RFI vulnerabilities come from improper handling of user input - basically, don't let user input get inside one of these include statements.